# Performance Testing using xUnit framework

Tags: xunit, performance-testing

I wonder if it is possible to run performance testing based on xUnit?

Comment: Are you asking about the xUnit.net framework, or just any 'xUnit' framework (as defined by the book *xUnit Test Patterns*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JUnit, you might look at [JUnitPerf](http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html).

If you're working in a different language and a different xUnit, the JunitPerf design concept (decorating normal JUnit tests) and code might give ideas of how to do the same in your language.

Comment: JUnitPerf is for Java. I need to test my C# codes. How one can test his/her C# code performance?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what exactly you asking, but you can easily write your own custom attribute to do that. For an example..

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TraceAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{

    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        //Start timer
    }


    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        //End timer
    }
}
```

Then decorate your Unit Test with the this attribute. Also make sure you write to an output ;)

Comment: for some cases it actually can help - but only for those, when a test run is LONG enough for the (highperf) timer to actually tick, and of course there are classic problems with concurrency and nondeterministic waits injected by the OS. real solution would at least run the given unit test ie. 100 times and measure he average speed. BUT, in xUnit, I currently do not know of any better way to measure the time than the one you have presented, and so there's a +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a project on Github : https://github.com/Microsoft/xunit-performance

It provides extensions over xUnit to author performance tests (benchmark).

Comment: > This repo has been archived, as this project is no longer maintained. We recommend that you use BenchmarkDotNet for your benchmarking needs.